# grails 3.3 spring security where is the beforeinsert to encrypt the password?

Tags: grails, spring-security

To add authentication to a grails 3 app you add this to the build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'
```

Then run

```
 grails s2-quickstart com.myapp Operator Role
```

This creates 3 domain objects, but nothing else I can find.

the Operator domain object looks like this:

```
package com.myapp

importgroovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
importgroovy.transform.ToString
importgrails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username',includeNames=true,includePackage=false)
classOperatorimplementsSerializable{

privatestaticfinallongserialVersionUID=1

Stringusername
Stringpassword
booleanenabled=true
booleanaccountExpired
booleanaccountLocked
booleanpasswordExpired

Set<Role>getAuthorities(){
(OperatorRole.findAllByOperator(this)asList<OperatorRole>)*.roleasSet<Role>
}

staticconstraints={
passwordnullable:false,blank:false,password:true
usernamenullable:false,blank:false,unique:true
}

staticmapping={
passwordcolumn:'
`password`'
}
}
```

The problem is, the before insert is missing to encrypt the password.  With grails 2.5, it used to put this into the Operator domain object:

```
    def beforeInsert() {
            encodePassword()
    }
```

So I expected the password to be inserted plain text, but it doesn't seem to be. It seems to be encrypted, at least for Operators created with bootstrap  The question is where and how?

Answer (score 3):

The old way of allowing domain classes to be subject to autowiring and injecting beans into each instance of a domain class cost quite a bit of memory. Later versions of Grails (3.3.x) opt for a `PreInsertEvent` listener to encode the password. This saves quite a bit of memory while achieving the same result. See the docs of s2quicktstart and the class `UserPasswordEncoderListener` which was created in your app.

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/index.html#tutorials

Comment: John, see the listener at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/530c3f200ad3d55de3cf7f6b1aeae1bbee31f319/misc-functional-test-app/grails-spring-security-hierarchical-roles/src/main/groovy/demo/UserPasswordEncoderListener.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to encode the password is to inject the method in Application.groovy.

My UserAccont class:

```
class UserAccount {

  //.. fields 

  def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
  }

  def beforeUpdate() {
    encodePassword()
  }

  String encodePassword() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException('Not implemented password encoder!' )
  }
}
```

The injection looks like:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {

  @Override
  void doWithDynamicMethods() {
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService = applicationContext.getBean 'springSecurityService'
    UserAccount.metaClass.encodePassword = {-> 
      delegate.password = springSecurityService.encodePassword delegate.password
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I don't have to `@Autowire` services in GORM entities. In my app also I could use domain classes from another GORM-standalode based module w/o SpringSec dependency.